# On the structure of the quotient of the ring of integers of a number field by an ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Letting $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$ denote the ring of integers of a number field $\mathbb{F}$ (a degree $d<\infty$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$), let $J$ be a proper ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$, and let $d_{J}$ denote $\left|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}/J\right|$. I have been told that, viewing $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}/J$ as an additive group, there is then a group isomorphism: $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}/J\cong C_{\rho_{1}}\times\cdots\times C_{\rho_{r}}$$ where $C_{k}$ is the cyclic group of order $k$, where $r\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,d_{J}\right\}$, and where $\rho_{1},\ldots,\rho_{r}$ are integers $\geq2$ so that $\rho_{i}\mid\rho_{i+1}$ for all $i\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,r-1\right\}$  and $\prod_{i=1}^{r}\rho_{i}=d_{J}$.

Assuming that I am not mistaken in writing the above, my question is: does there then exist a set $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$ which is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the group $\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}},+\right)$, so that, for any $d$-tuple $\mathbf{m}=\left(m_{1},\ldots,m_{d}\right)\in\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ representing an element $z\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$, the equivalence class of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}/J$ to which $z$ belongs is then completely determined by the values $m_{1}$ mod $\rho_{1}$, $m_{2}$ mod $\rho_{2}$, ..., $m_{r}$ mod $\rho_{r}$?

Comment: That structural assertion is true for any finite abelian group, no matter where it arose. Doesn't need anything about rings of algebraic integers $\mathfrak o$, and doesn't tell us much about them, either, since ignoring the $\mathfrak o$-module structure on ideals or on the quotients.

Comment: So, does this mean that the conclusion I make in the second paragraph is true?

Comment: Yes, indeed, your second-paragraph conclusion is correct, but it may not be as useful/interesting as you'd hoped, because the "mod $\rho_j$" stuff is _not_ quite visible in $\mathbb o/J$.

Comment: Quite the contrary, it is *quite* useful for what I intend to do. This is just the set-up, and I was worried the set-up was mistaken somewhere. Now that I know it is solid, I can proceed with confidence with my actual analytic study. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ok! Good! :) (Indeed, sometimes simpler/more-elementary features of seemingly fancy objects are all one needs... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: Does the integer $r$ have a well-established name—something like "the [noun] of $J$"? The only term I can find for $r$ is "the number of invariant factors of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}/J$", which is quite a mouthful. xD